# left hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Trying to put an integer data from database(Linq to sql) into a label getting this error exception:

> left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or
>   indexer

**Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataClassesDataContext data = new DataClassesDataContext();

   var visit = (from v in data.SeeSites where v.Date == todaydate select v).FirstOrDefault();
   int seennow = visit.See; // On This line I can put data in seenow variable, no problem

   Convert.ToInt64(lblSeeNow.Text) = visit.See;   // exception error appears here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
if (visit.See != null) {
    lblSeeNow.Text = visit.See.ToString();
}
```

You cannot assign something *to* a function result. In your case `lblSeeNow.Text` is of type String hence usage of ToString(); method of your Int value.

Comment: When I use This code I get This error :                           Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What error? Can you post the message?

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error: 
lblSeeNow.Text = Convert.ToString(visit.See);

Comment: Apparently your `visit.See` can return Null values. Please see my revised answer. And why are u using Convert.ToString?

Comment: Thanks I got it, Convert.ToString is a function and We can't assign something to it. But why This new error happens? I checked the database and "allow nulls" is not checked for See column.

Comment: @farhang67 - It doesn't mean there's a `null` in your database.  It means that there's no rows that match your query.  In other words, no row has a `Date` column that matches the value of `todaydate`.

Comment: unfortunately error still happens, the error message is the same and "if (visit.See != null)" is red.

Comment: There's a row in database and ID,date,See is set. thanks for your time

Comment: @farhang67, just check visit != null, not visit.See != null. It seems the query is not retrieving any visit then you have visit = null

Comment: @EstebanElverdin, I checked and worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
 lblSeeNow.Text = visit.See.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToInt64(lblSeeNow.Text) = visit.See;
```

As you mentioned, this is the issue.

`Convert.ToInt64` is a method.  But you're trying to save a value to it.

You can't.

Just do this

```
lblSeeNow.Text = visit.See.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the integer to string, also add a check for being sure that visit is not null

```
lblSeeNow.Text = visit != null ? visit.See.ToString() : string.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
lblSeeNow.Text = visit.See.ToString();
```

You can't assign anything to

```
Convert.ToInt64(lblSeeNow.Text)
```

because it evaluates to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt64(lblSeeNow.Text) isn't a variable.  It takes the value in lblSeeNow.Text and converts it to a long.  There isn't a variable to store stuff in anymore.

You probably want this:

```
lblSeeeNow.Text = visit.See.ToString();
```